# Finding weight on various different planets

Tags: java, beginner

I'm hoping I could get some help in understanding as well as optimizing code! I've been working on a few exercises on some online resources, and I decided to try and take it to the next level and start using methods.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SpaceBoxing 
{
    static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        double weight = getEarthWeight();       
        int choice = getPlanetChoice();
        double realWeight = computeEffectiveWeight(weight, choice);
        System.out.println("Your weight would be " + realWeight + " on that planet. ");
    }

    static double getEarthWeight()
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter your current Earth weight: ");
        return keyboard.nextDouble();
    }

    static int getPlanetChoice()
    {
        System.out.println("I have information on the following planets: ");
        System.out.println("1. Venus");
        System.out.println("2. Mars");
        System.out.println("3. Jupiter");
        System.out.println("4. Saturn");
        System.out.println("5. Uranus");
        System.out.println("6. Neptune");
        return keyboard.nextInt();
    }

    static double computeEffectiveWeight(double weight, int choice)
        {
            double realWeight = 0;
            if(choice == 1)
                realWeight = (weight * 0.78);

            else if(choice == 2)
                realWeight = (weight * 0.39);

            else if(choice == 3)
                realWeight = (weight * 2.65);

            else if(choice == 4)
                realWeight = (weight * 1.17);

            else if(choice == 5)
                realWeight = (weight * 1.05);

            else if(choice == 6)
                realWeight = (weight * 1.23);

            return realWeight;
        }
}
```

I've been working on calling methods and passing parameters between them, and so far I think I've got 2/3 of the methods completed except for the final one. Just a quick run down, I'm using the first two methods to return a typed input, and saving them into weight and choice. And the final method will take those two variables and computes a final result, which I hope to be able to print out. I'm not sure what to return the input values as, because I'm trying to pull the parameter and use it in another... instead of passing it in.

I'm not sure, but what am I missing? Are there some style things that I should do? Is there a better way in doing this (still with methods though)?

Answer (score 7):

> it's definitely WAY above what I've learned so far

So I try...

### An answer for beginners

The code is mostly alright, sure, using an `enum` would help and so would Java 8 features. But let's state the simple things:

```
public class SpaceBoxing 
{
```

The opening brace should be written on the same line and separated by a single space.

```
static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
```

You're creating a `Scanner`, which is `Closeable` and ideally should be closed. Usually, failing to do so means leaking resources and can make your program crash (e.g., you can't open a file as there are already 1000 open file descriptors).

But you're lucky: Your `Scanner` only wraps the underlying `InputStream` `System.in` and itself uses no system resources. So let's forget it for now.

---

```
static double computeEffectiveWeight(double weight, int choice)
    {
        double realWeight = 0;
```

Be consistent. Is the weight "real" or "effective"?

```
        if(choice == 1)
```

Space after `if` (to distinguish it visually from a method call).

You'd better always use braces, even around a single statement as it's less error-prone.

```
            realWeight = (weight * 0.78);
```

Needless parentheses. And also a needless variable. It'd clearer to write

```
        if (choice == 1) {
            return weight * 0.78;

        } else if (choice == 2) {
            return weight * 0.39;

        ...

        } else {
            return 0;
        }
```

But you probably should throw an `IllegalArgumentException` instead of returning 0 for an illegal argument.

Actually, this is a clear case for a switch:

```
       switch (choice) {
           case 1: return weight * 0.78;
           case 2: return weight * 0.39;
           ...
           default: return 0; // or better throw
       }
```

---

> I'll definitely look into it more, but I got the code working, and I guess "why break it if it ain't broke"

That's a good rule in general, but after applying it consequently for one month, you'll wish you never wrote a single line. ;) Don't hesitate to change code if it can get clearer and simpler. *Learn writing tests so you don't have to be afraid of change.*

### Simple enum usage

As the next step, I'd go for `enum Planet` exactly like h.j.k. did. Modify `getPlanetChoice` to return it like

```
static Planet getPlanetChoice() {
    Planet[] planets = Planet.values();
    while (true) {
        System.out.println("I have information on the following planets: ");
        System.out.println("1. Venus");
        System.out.println("2. Mars");
        System.out.println("3. Jupiter");
        System.out.println("4. Saturn");
        System.out.println("5. Uranus");
        System.out.println("6. Neptune");
        int index = keyboard.nextInt() - 1;
        if (0 <= index && index < planets.length) {
            return planets[index];
        }
        System.out.println("\nPlease try again.\n");
    }
}
```

and then get the needed information out of the returned `Planet`.

Comment: Wow! Thanks so much, I've learned about switches but I guess it never came up as an option to use! Also, I guess I've always returned a declared variable, I never realized I could return a "calculation".  

I know another commenter posted about it, but if it's possible, are you also able to simplify the usage of enums?

Answer (score 4):

**Enums**

Looking at the logic inside `computeEffectiveWeight()` suggests that they can be better encapsulated within `enum` values, with the given name say `Planet`. This will then allow us to easily:

1. Add new options/planets
2. Re-arrange their order

   - (advanced) sort the ordering based on names or factors

In your current code, if I wanted to add `Mercury` as the *first* option, I'll have to manually update your menu (to shift the indices), and also the `if`-ladder.

Here's how you can write it:

```
enum Planet {
    VENUS(0.78), MARS(0.39), JUPITER(2.65), SATURN(1.17), URANUS(1.05), NEPTUNE(1.23);

    private final double factor;

    private Planet(double factor) {
        this.factor = factor;
    }

    double getEffectiveWeight(double weight) {
        return weight * factor;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return (ordinal() + 1) + ". " + name();
    }
}
```

What this tells us is that each enumerated value has a `getEffectiveWeight()` method that will do the calculation for us. Displaying them and picking a choice is relatively trivial too:

```
private static Planet getPlanet() {
    System.out.println("I have information on the following planets: ");
    Stream.of(Planet.values()).forEach(System.out::println);
    return Planet.values()[keyboard.nextInt() - 1];
}
```

I'm using a Java 8 feature to stream each `enum` value to `System.out.println()` (used as a [method reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html)), and in this case since the values' `toString()` will be called, I am formatting the `String` display by overriding that method above. Then, I am choosing the value based on `keyboard.nextInt() - 1`, since we are printing it as a 1-based index.

Side-note: I generally prefer validating the user input by doing a `getLine()` and then using one of the [primitive wrapper conversion methods (linked to the `Integer` implementation)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt-java.lang.String-), allowing for re-prompting if the input is invalid. Just food for thought.

**`try-with-resources`**

If you are on Java 7, you should be using [`try-with-resources`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) on your `Scanner` too. This means making it a field inside your `main()` method, and passing it to the other two methods that require it to get a value.

**Putting it all together**

Now we're back to the `main()` method. The easy way is back to your original approach, to save the inputs before performing the calculation:

```
double weight = getEarthWeight(keyboard);
Planet planet = getPlanetChoice(keyboard);
double realWeight = planet.getEffectiveWeight(weight);
```

Alternatively, you can construct a stream-based processing:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)) {
        DoubleStream.of(getEarthWeight(scanner))
            .map(getPlanet(scanner)::getEffectiveWeight).forEach(v -> {
                System.out.println("Your weight would be " + v + " on that planet. ");
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow... thanks so much!! Uhm, it's definitely WAY above what I've learned so far, but I was able to do the very top part aha. I was able to change how the methods were declared and called, but past the ENUM and Streams, were just over my head... I'll definitely look into it more, but I got the code working, and I guess "why break it if it ain't broke"

Comment: In my opinion, the stream-based solution is abusive.

Comment: @200_success agreed, it's only helpful if we wanted to accept more than one input for weights.